# Bottom Navigation With List View in Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

I've create this code to call ListView in my activity and it work, here is the code

```
public class PegawaiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    String namapegawai;
    List<String> IdList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView StudentListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String HttpUrl = "http://192.168.43.241/Android/MyKoperasi/SemuaMember.php";

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    //mTextMessage.setText(namapegawai);
                    selectedFragment = PegawaiFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);

                    selectedFragment = MemberFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                //case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                   // mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    //break;
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pegawai);



        StudentListView = findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        new GetHttpResponse(PegawaiActivity.this).execute();



        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        //Manually displaying the first fragment - one time only
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, PegawaiFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();
    }

    // JSON parse class started from here.
    public class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;

        String JSonResult;

        List<Member> studentList;

        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            // Passing HTTP URL to HttpServicesClass Class.
            HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(HttpUrl);
            try
            {
                httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                if(httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                    if(JSonResult != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);

                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                            Member member;
                            studentList = new ArrayList<Member>();

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                member = new Member();
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Adding Student Id TO IdList Array.
                                IdList.add(jsonObject.getString("id").toString());
                                //Adding Student Name.
                                member.nama = jsonObject.getString("nama").toString();
                                member.nrp = jsonObject.getString("nrp").toString();
                                studentList.add(member);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            StudentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if(studentList != null) {
                ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(studentList, context);
                StudentListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Tidak ada data ditampilkan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Yes it's show the ListView item, but it show in my activity layout, not in fragment layout

how to show it in different bottom navigation

```
@Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        //mTextMessage.setText(namapegawai);
                        selectedFragment = PegawaiFragment.newInstance();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        //mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);

                        selectedFragment = MemberFragment.newInstance();
                        break;
                    //case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                       // mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                        //break;
                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        };
```

what code I used to call the ListView to show in different fragment on bottom navigation
thanks

======================UPDATE
My memberfragment

```
public class MemberFragment extends Fragment {
    public static MemberFragment newInstance() {
        MemberFragment fragment = new MemberFragment();
        return fragment;
    }
    TextView textViewNamaHolder;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_member, container, false);

        getActivity().setTitle("Daftar Member");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //List<Member> studentList = ((PegawaiActivity) getActivity());
        //PegawaiActivity a = new PegawaiActivity();
        //PegawaiActivity.GetHttpResponse mm = a.new GetHttpResponse(getActivity());
        //mm.execute();
        //Adding ListView Item click Listener.


        return v;
    }
}
```

and also my PegawaiFragment

```
public class PegawaiFragment extends Fragment {
    public static PegawaiFragment newInstance() {
        PegawaiFragment fragment = new PegawaiFragment();
        return fragment;
    }
    TextView textViewNamaHolder;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pegawai, container, false);

        getActivity().setTitle("Daftar Member");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //List<Member> studentList = ((PegawaiActivity) getActivity());
        //PegawaiActivity a = new PegawaiActivity();
        //PegawaiActivity.GetHttpResponse mm = a.new GetHttpResponse(getActivity());
        //mm.execute();
        //Adding ListView Item click Listener.


        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Share your Fragment layout and its related code

Comment: update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move your `listview` from `Activity` to both `Fragment`'s `(fragment_member)` and `(pegawai_fragment)` layout file.
2. Pass that `ListView` from both `Fragment` to `PegawaiActivity`
   's `GetHttpResponse` class  on `Fragment`.

**I have  updated your code. May be it will work.**

**GetHttpResponse on PegawaiActivity  .java**

```
// GetHttpResponse  class on PegawaiActivity  
    public class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;

        String JSonResult;

        List<Member> studentList;
private ListView listView;

        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

public void setListView(ListView listView){
      this.listView = listView;
}

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            // Passing HTTP URL to HttpServicesClass Class.
            HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(HttpUrl);
            try
            {
                httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                if(httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                    if(JSonResult != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);

                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                            Member member;
                            studentList = new ArrayList<Member>();

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                member = new Member();
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Adding Student Id TO IdList Array.
                                IdList.add(jsonObject.getString("id").toString());
                                //Adding Student Name.
                                member.nama = jsonObject.getString("nama").toString();
                                member.nrp = jsonObject.getString("nrp").toString();
                                studentList.add(member);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            StudentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if(studentList != null) {
                ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(studentList, context);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Tidak ada data ditampilkan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

**MemberFragment .java**

```
    public class MemberFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView studentListView;
            public static MemberFragment newInstance() {
                MemberFragment fragment = new MemberFragment();
                return fragment;
            }
            TextView textViewNamaHolder;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_member, container, false);

                studentListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
                getActivity().setTitle("Daftar Member");
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);
                //PegawaiActivity a = new PegawaiActivity();
        PegawaiActivity.GetHttpResponse mm = a.new 
        GetHttpResponse(getActivity());
        mm.setListView(studentListView );
        mm.execute();
        //Adding ListView Item click Listener.

                return v;
            }

        }
```

Comment: and how to use it in PegawaiFragment? do I need create this code to?

Comment: Can't we just make the code in activity and call it in 2 fragments?

Comment: Yes, you can. It will depend on your requirement. But logically its possible.

Comment: I already figured out this code, but I think this code is useless, using same code for two fragments, what I want is to make one code become available to two fragments

Comment: What about the data between two fragmaents?? these would be same??

Comment: yes, that's ok, i just want to make the code simple to make one code can be use by 2 fragments

Comment: Then use Activity's `GetHttpResponse` class. Pass your `studentList` listview from both  `MemberFragment` and `PegawaiFragment ` to Activity's `GetHttpResponse` class and use this listview on `OnPostExecute` method. Also Remove   `GetHttpResponse` class  from both Fragments.

Comment: Can you help me with the code? don't know about what should i edit